# UIWebView и выполнение JS кода

Tags: xcode, javascript

Основная загвоздка в том, что нужно подгружать .js файл, как это сделать?
Вот код:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://...../module/ts_sale_module.js" charset="utf-8"></script> 
<DIV id="ts_sale_result" align=center></DIV> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
TS_Sale_Module({ columns: "4", rows: "10", stars: "0", rating: "0", city: "3", searchlink: "http://......", countries: "" }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

выполнить java script и получить его результаты, если нужно, можно с помощью:

```
NSString *results = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"your java script here"];
```